# How does Moses opt to use הָ֣אֱלֹהִ֔ים for judges in Exodus 21:6?

Tags: hebrew, exodus, law, moses, kjv

Exodus 21:6 KJV

> 6 Then his master shall bring him unto the ***judges***;  he shall also bring him to the door, or unto the door post;  and his master shall bore his ear through with an awl;  and he shall serve him for ever

והגישו אדניו אל־***האלהים*** והגישו אל־הדלת או אל־המזוזה ורצע אדניו את־אזנו במרצע ועבדו לעלם׃ ס

All the authors of the old testament and Moses used the word ***שֹׁפְטֵ֖י*** for judges but only in the book of Exodus did Moses choose to use ***הָ֣אֱלֹהִ֔ים***  in reference to judges.

Could there be some significance why he chose to use this word only in the book of Exodus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use of God in reference to judges follows an episode in Exodus 7:1:

> And the Lord said to Moses: See now that I have appointed you the God of Pharaoh: and Aaron your brother shall be your prophet.

Perhaps Moses is simply continuing with this convention of speaking of those which divine authority over others (of which judges partake as such).

See also this usage with reference to judges in Psalms (Psalm 82):

> God stands in the congregation of God. He judges among gods.
>
> How long will you render iniquitous judgement, and show partiality to the wicked? Show judgement to the poor, and the orphan, and the lowly: bring justice to the destitute. Deliver the poor and the needy: recure them from the hands of the wicked. They know nothing, and have no understanding: they go about in darkness; the foundations of the earth move beneath them.
>
> I said: You are gods, and sons, every one of you, of the Highest. Nevertheless you shall die as men, and shall fall as any prince.
>
> Arise, O God: judge the earth, that you might have an inheritance in all the nations.

Comment: "Gods" in v.8 should instead be translated by the singular "God" as it utilizes the pronoun אַתָּ֥ה (masculine singular) in the same verse.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the oversight!